# How do I set a variable from an external command in ansible

Tags: ansible

As a part of an ansible playbook, I am writing a logfile on the machines that have been manipulated by the script. Since the ansible files is in a git repository, it is relevant to know which version was checked out during the run. At the moment I add on the command line

```
--extra-vars "git_version=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)"
```

this gives me the information I want to use, but it also means this has to be manually added on any run of the playbook. I tried using the shell: command as a task,

```
- name: Read git commit  
  shell: /usr/bin/git rev-parse --short HEAD
  register: git_version
```

but that of course failed spectaculary as it was executed on the clients, not the server. So, how can I run the git command (or any other command) on the server to store the informatioion in an ansible variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`delegate_to: localhost`* and *`run_once: true`* is what you're looking for. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - command: git rev-parse --short HEAD
      register: git_version
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: git_version.stdout
      run_once: true
```

See:

- [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#controlling-where-tasks-run-delegation-and-local-actions)
- [Running on a single machine with run_once](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once)

Note: *" ... with run_once, the results are applied to all the hosts."* As a result, the variable *git_version* registered in the first task will be available to all hosts in the play.